# How to log every logger info to my sentry not only Exception and group by the current route name in flutter

Tags: flutter, sentry

#### Background

At the beginning, I planned to use SentryNavigator Observer to automatically report and set the traceSampleRate to 1.0. The code is as follows:

```dart
await SentryFlutter.init((options) {
      options.dsn = 'my dsn';
      options.environment = Global.isRelease ? 'production' : 'development';
      options.release =
          '${packageInfo.packageName}@${packageInfo.version}+${packageInfo.buildNumber}';
      options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
      options.maxBreadcrumbs = 10000;
    });
```

But I found that it wasn't used. I can only see some routing reports in the Discovery panel

So where exactly is the problem ？